# Add <comma><space>DEBUG to the end of line 3 in a text file with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

On windows/batch, this is line 3: `log4j.logger.com.=INFO, FILE, STDOUT, STDERR` at the end of the line i'm trying to edit it so it will look like this: `log4j.logger.com.=INFO, FILE, STDOUT, STDERR, DEBUG`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially a repeat of [your already closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549190/add-one-word-to-the-end-of-specific-line-line-3-with-batch) from less than a week ago. It also appears that you haven't learned anything as a result of that question being closed!

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044): `jrepl "$" ", DEBUG" /exc "/, DEBUG$/" /inc 3 /f test.txt /o -`